# Speed test: while() cycle vs. jQuery's each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects called `targets` and I want to execute a function on each of those objects. The first method:

```
targets.each(function() {
    if (needScrollbars($(this))) {
        wrap($(this), id);
        id = id + 1;
    }
});
```

This method gives execution speed of ~125ms. The second method is:

```
var i=0;
while (targets[i] != undefined) {
    if (needScrollbars($(this))) {
        wrap($(this), id);
        id = id + 1;
    }
    i = i+1;
}
```

This second method takes whopping 1385ms to execute and I get my head around that. Does anyone have any idea why a bare bones cycle runs slower than a function which I'm only guessing that's doing (just guessing) a whole lot more than a simple cycle?

Thank you.

Comment: Please create a http://jsperf.com/ test.

Comment: 1)Faulty `this` value gets `window`, 2)Using `!=` instead of `!==` leads to type coercion and decreased performance

Comment: I made some corrections and tried to make a jsperf.com test, but I get some weird errors. Felix Kling, can you take a look please? http://jsperf.com/while-cycle-vs-each

Comment: Have not corrected it yet, but you know that your `needScrollbars` function first prepends a new element and then immediately removes it? Is this intended?

Comment: Some comments to your test: First, put as few code as possible inside each test case and only put the code that you want to test. E.g. you don't want to test how fast a function declaration is or how long it takes to find all `article`s. Though it is only a relative error in the same test run, it can falsify results when you compare different browsers. Second, why are you making it so complicated to retrieve all `article` elements? `var target = $('article');` is sufficient. Here is an improved version: http://jsperf.com/while-cycle-vs-each/2 both methods seem to be equally fast...

Answer (score 2):

They are totally different. The `this` in the first example is the current `target`, in the second example `this` is the "external" `this`. You should change the second example as:

```
var i=0;
while (targets[i] != undefined) {
    var cur = $(targets[i]);
    if (needScrollbars(cur)) {
        wrap(cur, id);
        id = id + 1;
    }
    i = i+1;
}
```

The relevant [quote](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.

But I don't know why you haven't written as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++)
{
    var cur = $(targets[i]);
    if (needScrollbars(cur)) {
        wrap(cur, id);
        id = id + 1;
    }
}
```

And in the end the `each` "method" is easier to comprehend (for me).

Comment: Wow, I have totally overlooked that. I will correct it and test it again.

Answer (score 2):

Your second method is not functionally equivalent to the first one.

Why? Because it uses `this`, making it a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) on the global scope. Of course the second method is slower: it continuously shells out jQuery objects made out of global scope. Try that benchmark again with:

```
var i=0;
while (targets[i] !== undefined) {
    var o = $(targets[i]);
    if (needScrollbars(o)) {
        wrap(o, id);
        id++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Only running the jQuery initializer once would be a good idea for the first snippet, too.